# Writing python lines in a .cmd file

Tags: python, command-prompt

I have python installed on my pc. When I open command prompt I type this line:

>python

---

After this I am able to write lines in python:

>>>print('kaas')

kaas

---

I want to write a .cmd file that does this automatically. When I write my cmd file like this, it does not work:

python

print('kaas')

---

Does anyone have suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `py -3 -c "print('kass')"`? (using the Windows launcher rather than relying on your `PATH` being configured properly)

Comment: Another option is to write some `my-script.py` file and then invoke `python my-script.py` from the `.cmd` file.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It works for only this line, what if I wanted to run more lines like this example:
a=1
b=2
c=3
print(c)

Comment: @9000 I tried this but I want to include it all in the .cmd file if that is possible

Comment: Python code that's more complex than a single line goes in a Python script. This is a text file with extension `.py` -- as the official docs say (https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html) and @9000 has told you, put your python code in a python file and, if you absolutely must, run it from a .cmd file.